# Testcafe: How to wait for the remote runner to be waiting/accepting connections before launching my browser?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

First and foremost, the "remote" function of Testcafe is easily one of the best and most portable browser testing implementations I have ever come across; excellent work to the team developing it.

When I run `npx testcafe remote ./tests --ports 5567,5568`

The runner will notify me that it's listening on `http://localhost:5567/browser/connect`. Fantastic, now I want to launch my browser and navigate to this URL.

My browser might be a headless browser inside a docker container, or it could be a remote server running MacOS - regardless of its location, the remote needs to be issued commands *after* the test runner is ready and accepting connections.

Is there an endpoint like `/ping` or something that I can send a request to that will notify me of the test runner's active status?

```sh
npx concurrently \
  "npx wait-on http://localhost:5567/ping && remote-browser-util IOS_SAFARI http://localhost:5567/browser/connect" \
  "npx testcafe remote ./tests --ports 5567,5568"
```

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe is ready to accept browser connections as soon as specified ports are occupied. So you can use `wait-on tcp:5567` to delay the start of your browser.